# Abstract Algebra Normal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I have a basic question related to abstract algebra, I read a proof in a book and partly below:

> $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H_1,H_2$ are two subgroups of $G$ containing $K$. Suppose $H_1/K = H_2/K$, then for any $h_1 \in H_1, h_1K \in H_2K$, so $h_1K = h_2K$ for some $h_2 \in H_2.$ Then $(h_2)^{-1}h_1\in K.$

I'm a little confused about the last sentence, how do we prove $(h_2)^{-1}h_1\in K$ rigorously?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for the suggestions, the book is Basic Algebra by Jacobson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just comes down to basic coset manipulations.  You have

$$h_1K = \{ h_1 k : k \in K\}.$$

You always have $h_1 \in h_1K$.  Therefore, if $h_1K = h_2K$, this means that there exists a $k \in K$ such that $h_1 = h_2k$.  Then $h_2^{-1}h_1 = k \in K$, as required.